# How do I update the values in CreateCanvas() for p5.js as the window resizes?

Tags: javascript, canvas, resize, p5.js, window-resize

I'm trying my hand at another coding project made completely out of JavaScript using the p5.js library - I don't really know how to use HTML. Anyway, in p5.js, there's a `createCanvas([width], [length])` function that creates a "canvas" to sort of draw on. I'm trying to make the canvas adjustable when the window resizes (e.g. pressing F11, making the window cover only half of the screen, etc.) but my problem is that I make the canvas in the `setup()` function, which only runs once. Is there a way to do one of three things:

---

Make the canvas run more than once while not affecting anything else, sort of like having a `clear()` function or like putting a `background()` function at the beginning of the `draw()` loop (in other words, would it change anything if I moved the `createCanvas()` function from `setup()` to `draw()`?)

Detect when the screen resizes and make a new canvas when that happens

Detect the overall screen size, in pixels, and then make a canvas that large, while just using `window.innerLength` or `window.innerHeight` to use only part of the canvas that is showing

---

Or am I doing this completely wrong, and do I need to take a different approach to screen resizing? I'm new to this aspect of coding :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, in p5.js there is a `windowResized()` event and a `resizeCanvas()` method that can resize canvas in accordance to your:

- windowWidth
- windowHeight

```
function setup() { 
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  noStroke();
} 

function draw() { 
  background(80);
  
  ellipse(width/2 , height/2 ,100,100);
}

function windowResized(){
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

Run code here: https://editor.p5js.org/aferriss/sketches/rJAwGb_AW

Comment: Wow, that's pretty much the most perfect thing that could've happened. Thanks for telling me about that!

Comment: Glad to help! :)